# Recovering a measure by knowing its integral

Tags: measure-theory, fourier-analysis

I have a space $\Theta$ (you can think of it as a circumference), a given function $f \in L^2(\Theta)$, a given function $\psi \in C^\infty(\Theta)$ (you can think of it as a Dirichlet kernel of order 7) and an UN-known measure $\eta$ on $\Theta$.

If we know that $$ f(\theta)=\int_{x\in\Theta}\psi(x-\theta)d\eta $$ holds for all $\theta \in \Theta$, can we recover the measure $\eta$?
If so, by what means (theorems/theory) can we do that?

Comment: I actually also know that I can write $\eta$ with respect to the lebesgue measure: $\eta(E)=\int_{ E} y_0(x) dx $ (of course, the purpose becomes finding $y_0$ now)

Comment: If I'm understanding the setup, $f$ is the convolution on the circle ($S^1$) of the measure $\eta$ with the reflection of $\psi$. The Fourier transform is helpful in this situation, as it converts convolution to multiplication. Unfortunately, the measure $\eta$ won't be uniquely defined if $\psi$ is a Dirichlet kernel, since the Fourier transform of $\psi$ has compact support and thus can't be fully "divided out".

Comment: @Jason Thank you very much. Could you please provide some (very simple) reference for understanding what you're saying? I only have a vague idea of this maths...

Comment: Here are a couple short sets of notes that cover how convolution with a Dirichlet kernel gives a partial sum of the Fourier series:
https://spot.colorado.edu/~baggett/fourier5.pdf, https://www.math.arizona.edu/~friedlan/teach/456/gibbs.pdf

Comment: And the Wikipedia page on Fourier series discusses how the Fourier transform converts convolution to multiplication: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series#Convolution_theorems